# Unable to run iDempiere model.generator in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, idempiere

I tried running the iDempiere(ver. 2.1 & 4.1) model.generator from Run Configurations in eclipse. Apparently, from the tutorial videos, I noticed that there should be a window that will pop-up where you can register which table you want to generate a model but in my case there is no pop-up

Here is the logs:

```
Feb 02, 2017 3:45:40 PM org.compiere.util.Language getLanguage
INFO: Adding Language=en, Country=PH, Locale=en_PH
15:45:40.596 Adempiere.startup: iDempiere(r) Release 4.1_2016-10-31 -Smart Suite ERP, CRM and SCM- (c) 1999-2016 iDempiere(r); Implementation: iDempiere - Supported by iDempiere community [1]
15:45:40.596 Ini.loadProperties: D:\SVN\SERVER\IDEMPIERE41\idempiere.properties #32 [1]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://31.fwk2129221032:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://31.fwk2129221032:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory]
15:45:41.155 DB.isBuildOK: Build DB=${env.ADEMPIERE_VERSION} 20080428-1232 [1]
15:45:41.155 DB.isBuildOK: Build Cl=4.1.0.qualifier [1]
15:45:41.175-----------> DB.isBuildOK: Build Version Error 

The program assumes build version 4.1.0.qualifier, but database has build version ${env.ADEMPIERE_VERSION} 20080428-1232. 
This is likely to cause hard to fix errors. 
Please contact administrator. [1]
15:45:41.245 Language.getLanguage: Adding Language=en, Country=US, Locale=en_US [1]
15:45:41.255 Language.getLanguage: Adding Language=en, Country=US, Locale=en_US [1]
usage: ModelGenerator folder packageName entityType tableName
```

Comment: I figured there might not be a pop-up and instead I should use the VM arguments in eclipse.

This part here is what I'm having a problem:

`usage: ModelGenerator folder packageName entityType tableName`

according to [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/idempiere/c9t1TLlT3pQ)
@Pedro Rozo mentioned that I need to specify the source folder. but even then I get this error

`Error: Could not find or load main class D:\SVN\SERVER\IDEMPIERE41\org.test.editor\src`
..............................
VM arguments:
`D:\SVN\SERVER\IDEMPIERE41\org.test.editor\src\ org.test.models D Test`

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you added wrong number of arguments in the "Run Configurations".

The popup window you're expecting is shown when the program is called without arguments.

If you want to run that with arguments, then you need to add exactly four arguments:
- folder
- packageName
- entityType
- tableName

Regards,

Carlos Ruiz
http://wiki.idempiere.org/wiki/User:CarlosRuiz

Comment: Hi, that's what I thought about the popup window, but when  I tried removing the arguments, there is no popup window and the logs just says:
`usage: ModelGenerator folder packageName entityType tableName`